# bash - proper way to automate compilation

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to automate the compilation of Mono under CentOS, and for that I'm writing a bash script. But I'm quite new to this and I'm not sure what the best practices here.

This is what my script looks like now:

```
# Variables
monoRepoUrl='http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono'

monoPackageName='mono-2.10.8'
monoSubdir=$monoPackageName
srcDirectory='/usr/local/src'/$monoSubdir

monoUrl=$monoRepoUrl'/'$monoSubdir'/'$monoPackageName".tar.bz2"

# Prepare environment
echo ''
echo 'Installing pre-requisites packages'
echo ''
yum -y install gcc-c++ make httpd-devel gettext bison


######### Mono core stuff #########
echo ''
echo 'Getting Mono'
echo ''
wget $monoUrl
tar jxvf $monoPackageName.tar.bz2

$srcDirectory/configure -prefix=/opt/$monoPackageName; $srcDirectory/make; $srcDirectory/make install
echo export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/$monoPackageName/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH>>~/.bash_profile
echo export PATH=/opt/$monoPackageName/bin:$PATH>>~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

echo ''
echo 'End of Mono installation'
echo ''
```

However, the problem I have here is that the changing of directory doesn't work - scripts seem to have their own process. What would be the more elegant way of doing this, keeping it simple (I'd rather not use functions unless it's absolutely necessary, for instance)?

Would using absolute path everywhere work? What is the best practice for that kind of situation in bash?

Comment: Usually, running a builder like GNU `make` is much better than making your `bash` script. And `mono` should preferably be installed thru the distribution's packaging system (e.g. `dpkg`, `apt-get`, `aptitude` .... on Debian, Mint or Ubuntu, or `yum` on Fedora or Redhat).

Comment: I don't see where you change directory.

Comment: Basile: There is absolutely no repo for Mono on CentOS, which is why I need to compile it in the first place. Changing OS is not an option.

Comment: But you could instead package Mono for CentOS (and contribute that, if possible, to the distro). So learn how to do packages in CentOS first.

Comment: Joni: I removed the cd command because it was useless since it was not really working.

Comment: For packaging I need to compile don't I? And anyway, this question is about bash, not providing package for CentOS.

Comment: There is absolutely no way to `cd` inside some script and have that `chdir` done in the parent process. Because a shell script runs in its own `sh` -or `bash`- process and the `chdir(2)` syscall done by `cd` affects only that shell process (and its future child processes).

Comment: Thanks Basile. You should post that as the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are writing a bash script make sure you always use absolute paths, bash doesn't accept or read the relative paths.Since you are newbie make sure you also specifies absolute path of a command, for example just yum might not work sometimes. Check which yum first get the absolute path of the yum and specify the absolute path in your bash scripts. Make sure you have given execute permission to the script also at the same time

Comment: -1 because `bash` is *not special* in its handling of paths. It uses `execvp` (or some internal equivalent), e.g. the `PATH` environment variable. And `PATH` could contain relative directories (even if that is often bad practice). A shell script could even change its own `PATH` if so wanted.